# Spliting join of multiple tables in PL-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, left-join

I need to create a function that returns a sysref cursor pointing to some result set.
I need to join a global temporary table with several other tables, 
the basic aproach would look like this:

```
 Open sysrefcur for
     select *
     from
       (select * 
       from globaltemptable) t1
       left join t2
         on <conditions1>
       left join t3
         on <conditions2>
       left join t4
         on <conditions2>
       ...
       ;
       return sysrefcur;
```

The problem is that I have to joint the global temporary table (GTT) with around 30 additional tables (I know, it's a lot) but DBAs set a limit of 10 joins,

So I was thinking of joining the GTT table with a few tables, inserting the result in another GTT, join it to another few tables and so on.

I want to know if theres a better approach to this and if I can avoid creating additional temporary tables at all.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does it meant limit 10 joins? Why you have such limit?

Comment: The better approach would be to make the business case, why a query that joins 30 tables is needed to "do your job". Then have the business decision makers override the DBA constraint, if it gets in the way of "doing the job." Of course, it is possible that you and the team will find out that whatever you need to do doesn't require a join of 30 tables after all; perhaps your solution is not optimal.

Comment: <RANT>Or, you will find a different approach that is far less optimal, take more resource that the amount the DBA was (presumably) trying to save. "10 joins" as completely as does nothing. The DB should learn to use Resource Manager and resource management as a discipline</RANT>

Comment: You need to sit down with your DBA and talk through the requirement. Perhaps he/she has seen several of these huge queries before and can suggest a better alternative. Maybe a design change is required, who knows.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I understand the right way to proceed would be talking with the DBAs about the bussines requierements and try to effectively adapt their policies to those requierements, unfortunately the DBAs are very closed minded and kind of rigid and un experienced, the company's policy is very Bureaucrat, I'll try to comply with the compay's policies this time but I appreciate your responses guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create views that do 5 joins each and then join 6 views.
2. Use CTE. Define `with` statements with some joins then join results of `with` statements.

Comment: I'd vote for CTE (aka subquery factoring, aka "the with clause") to do this. Of course, if your DBAs have set a limit of 10 joins, this isn't likely to actually limit the query to 10 joins, since query rewriting will most likely happen.

Comment: Thanks @kacper, I didn't know you can immediatly make reference to the tables you just created using `WITH` i.e. it's possible to do `with tbl1 as (select 1 as col1 from tst), tbl2 as (select * from (select * from tbl1))        select * from tbl1 cross join tbl2` whereas is not possible to do `select * from (select 1 as col1 from tst) tbl1 cross join (select * from (select * from tbl1)) tbl2`. I used your suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you suggested in your post is probably best.  It is simple to implement and understand, not horribly less efficient than doing this the right way (I'll second/third the criticisms of your DBA's policy), and it clearly conforms to the policy.  (Using views or CTEs are arguably "violations", since, at end of it all, it's a 30-table query still).

> and if I can avoid creating additional temporary tables at all.

You can avoid creating an additional global temp table if you are able to add placeholder columns to the one you have.  In that case, your solution would look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE globaltemptable ADD ... placeholder columns for T2, T3, T4, etc data...


MERGE INTO globaltemptable t
USING ( SELECT * FROM globaltemptable t1
        LEFT JOIN ... t2 through t10  (10 table join) ...
      ) u
ON ( t.primary_key = u.primary_key )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ... t2 through t10 columns in globaltemptable ...
;

... repeat merge for tables t11 through t19

... repeat merge for tables t20 through t28

... repeat merge for tables t29 through t30


OPEN SYSREFCUR FOR SELECT * FROM globaltemptable -- no joins.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Matthew. Yes, using CTEs you'll end up with a 30 table query as well, the dbas policy consists on not doing more that 10 joins in the same query, so for them doing three subqueries with 10 joins each and then joining them all is a valid policy, so I took @kacper approach but I'm grateful you share your alternative with us, for me it consists of a more advanced concept I'll be able to stud and learn.